# Is it possible to compile Java on a webserver?

Tags: java, apache, nginx, webserver

By using the JRE or some other runtime environment, is it possible to compile Java code on a web server such as Apache or Nginx?
Specifically, I would like to have a web application that would accept user input (Java code), and when the user hits run, it would compile the Java into Java Byte code and display the result, like Eclipse does.
Does this sort of technology even exist?
Does this defy the logic of compiled languages?
Thank you for your time in advance.
Amicably,
James

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The server running Apache would also need a JDK. You could easily write the input to a file, compile it, run it, and display the results to the user. This could be done with a CGI script, or a Java EE app or similar, running in Tomcat. A JDK will be required, a JRE will not suffice.

Consider the potential security risk with this, though. Depending on what the program actually does, it could result in problems on your machine or others.

Comment: Just supporting Beau's comment on security here. The code that the user writes will run on your server. He could access files, make system calls etc. It is possible to tighten this up by using security managers in Java and restrict the java process, but don't do this unless you really know what you are doing.

Comment: Awesome, got it.  Thanks.  However, whenever a compilation request sent to the server, is it possible to run the Java code in a VM?

Answer (score 1):

Of course this is possible. But you need a JDK, and some server side scripts (PHP, Ruby, Python, Java ...) which takes the source code as input and calls the Java compiler to compile the code.
What you have to consider are the security implications. Every user could then upload code, which would be executed on the server. So you have to make sure, that the code runs in a sandbox.

Answer (score 1):

There are several websites that do this. One that I've used is at http://www.ideone.com.

You can reproduce this with the JDK and various scripts or you can write your own compiler from scratch. Either way, you need a compiler of some kind to actually compile the code.